# Site Actions menu in SharePoint is WSS-like, whereas I have installed MOSS

Tags: sharepoint, moss, wss

I had WSS installed on my VM and then uninstalled in order to install MOSS Enterprise

I can see a lot of the MOSS stuff in the Central Administration pages but when I create a new web application and site collection, my Site Actions dropdown is showing the WSS version, i.e.  Create, Edit Page and Site Settings as opposed to the MOSS menu which has View All Site Content, View Reports, Manage Content and Structure etc.

I just tried deleting my web app and creating it all again but it's come back with the same thing again.

Is somewhere remembering that I used to have WSS installed? (yes I know MOSS is built on top of WSS but you know what I mean!)

Answer (score 2):

Got it - had to enable "Office SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure" in Site Collection features and then activate "Office SharePoint Server Publishing" from the site in question.

Now appears fine

Answer (score 0):

If you want the menus like View Reports, Manage Content and Structure etc.. you need to activate "Office SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure" feature from the site collection featire.

When you create new site using published site template, the "Office SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure" feature is activated defaultly.